# Triggers vs stored procedure vs inline SQL in DAL for updating tables in a database with history

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

Say if I have a database with history tables:

[SomeTable]

```
SomeColumn1
SomeColumn2
UpdatedDTM
UpdatedUserID
IsObselete
```

[SomeTableHistory]

```
SomeColumn1
SomeColumn2
UpdatedDTM
UpdatedUserID
AuditedDTM
```

When a row in SomeTable is updated, the following needs to happen:

- The row in SomeTable needs inserting into SomeTableHistory.
- The row in SomeTable needs updating with the new values.
- The UpdatedDTM column in SomeTable needs setting to the current time.

My first thought was to use stored procedures:

```
add_sometable_entry(SomeColumn1, SomeColumn2, UserID)
update_sometable_entry(ID, SomeColumn1, SomeColumn2, UserID)
expire_sometable_entry(ID, UserID)
```

Then I wondered if maybe I should use triggers instead, allowing the usual "insert into sometable" and "update sometable" sql calls to work on SomeTable and with the history mechanisms working automatically.

Or course then there is the option of just inlining the sql to do this for each history table within the DAL.

I'm currently leaning towards the stored procedures so I can keep the DAL clean, and also only allowing insert/update/delete access to the database via the stored procedures which will help to stop distributors/customers from "having a play" and manipulating the tables directly.

What are peoples thoughts/experience on this?

I'm using PostgreSQL (though that should have no bearing, should it?..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIC, the users should not be able to insert/update/delete the tables directly (unless you want chaos and complete loss of data/referential Integrity.  That should be allowed from stored procedures only, which ensure that the whatever Transactions (business functions) are allowed, are executed within the context of a Transaction; Atomic as per ACID Properties; that it is correct and complete; errors are handled consistently; etc.

Triggers are incapable of that.

Now, with a Historic or Audit requirement, which should be transactional, that is merely adding a few lines to the existing Transactions/stored procs.  It would absurd to deploy half the code in stored procs and the rest in triggers; and if you do the trigger code unnecessarily complicates the otherwise clean transaction code.

The only circumstance where triggers are worth considering is, where you have a Non-SQL, eg. no Transactions **and** no stored procs (if it had either one and not the other, I would still normalise the code segments).  In that circumstance, sure, deploy the code for maintaining historic tables in triggers, and the rest elsewhere.

Of course, the business logic that relates to the database, should be in the database, not outside it. Eg. in the real world beyond tiny Non-SQLs, a single corporate database may be used by five apps: all the validation and the transactions for the Db reside in one place, in the Db.  It would be stupid to place that anywhere outside the Db.

- There is a separate requirement, that the DAL should not attempt invalid actions, which waste server resources; and therefore it must check or validate every action before attempting it.  That is not "duplicating" such validation code which may exist at the top of each transaction; it saves both the user interaction time and server resources.

Comment: *"in the real world beyond tiny Non-SQLs, a single corporate database may be used by five apps: all the validation and the transactions for the Db reside in one place, in the Db. It would be stupid to place that anywhere outside the Db."* well, thats one way of doing it, but have you ever heard of middleware and domain models being used for business rules? I certainly have.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are powerful, but tend to be a pain, as they are hard to test/debug.

You could argue that Stored Procedures would be better.

But if you're going to be writing 'code', you could argue that (rather than in an SP) its much nicer to put code in the DAL, where its easier to get version control, unit testing, debugging etc.

Finally, if you look at 'all updates to (someentity) should be recorded as (someentityhistory)' as a business rule (aka domain rule), then you could argue that in your business-logic-layer (aka domain logic layer) you should have code that implements this rule. So that would move the code up above the DAL into the Business-Layer. (so that it would be dealing with entity objects rather than SQL).

One factor to bear in mind is: if someone is importing data or doing bulk data updates, are they going to do it via the business layer (through an API or something) or with direct database access? If its direct database access, and you still want this rule to fire, then that might be an argument for triggers.

In summary: you could argue.

Comment: Good point re bulk updates - I think it'd have to be via the business layer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of triggers in general, but this is one usage of them that I wouldn't object to.

However, there are other benefits to stored procedures as you have said to enforce only permitted, valid updates to the tables.  And if you are going to have stored procedures for those reasons then they may as well do the auditing while they are about it!

Answer (score 0):

For storing the history, the *tablelog* addon might be helpful. 
http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty handy - however for this particular project I'm trying to keep things fairly database agnostic.